# Is there documentation for TfLiteTensor available

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tflite

In the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/cc/namespace/tflite) of tflite API for C++, many methods have TfLiteTensor or a pointer to such type as return value (e.g., [input_tensor() method.](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/cc/class/tflite/interpreter#input_tensor). Is there any reference to which attributes and methods are available for TfLiteTensor class?

I looked in the official Tflite documentation, googled around and went through the source code on github, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TfLiteTensor is part of the TensorFlow Lite C API project and is a C struct (not a c++ class). I'm not seeing any way to generate documentation for it explicitly, nor do I see anything on line. The code API read me is located here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/c/README.md

the TfLiteTensor definition is here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/c/common.h#L526

Comment: For anyone looking for the definition it has been moved https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/core/c/common.h